# Checking initial condition of PDE is satisfied in Galerkin method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

The following is an argument I read, it is part of a proof of checking that **the solution given by the Galerkin method satisfies the initial conditions**.

From our PDE
$$\langle u', v \rangle_{V',V} + a(u, v) = \langle f, v \rangle_{V',V}$$
which holds for all $v \in L^2(0,T;V)$, we can pick $v \in C^1(0,T;V)$ with $v(T) = 0$ and integrate this equation in time and use integration by parts to obtain
$$\int_0^T -\langle u, v' \rangle_{V',V} + \int_0^T a(u,v) = \int_0^T\langle f, v \rangle_{V'V} + (u(0),v(0))_H.\tag{1}$$

Now we must use our Galerkin approximation
$$\int_0^T\langle u_m', v_n \rangle_{V',V} + \int_0^Ta(u_m,v_n) = \int_0^T\langle f, v_n \rangle_{V',V}\tag{a}$$
and do some integration by parts and pass to the limit to obtain 
$$\int_0^T -\langle u, v' \rangle_{V',V} + \int_0^T a(u,v) = \int_0^T\langle f, v \rangle_{V'V} + (u_0,v(0))_H\tag{2}$$
where $v \in C^1(0,T;H)$ with $v(T) = 0$. This works because we know $u_m(0) \to u_0$, the initial condition.

Comparing (1) and (2), we can conclude $u(0) = u_0$.

**Reasoning to obtain equation (2)**

We have the convergences $u_m \rightharpoonup u$ in $L^2(0,T;V)$ and $u'_m \rightharpoonup u'$ in $L^2(0,T;V')$, where the $u_m \in V_m$. Pick $v_n \in V_n$ such that $v_n \to v$ in $L^2(0,T;V).$ Note that $v_n = \sum_{j=1}^n a_{j,n}w_j$ where $w_j$ is an o.n basis of $H$ and o.g basis of $V$.

We obtain from (a) the equation
$$-\int_0^T\langle u_m, v_n' \rangle_{V',V} + \int_0^Ta(u_m, v_n) = \int_0^T\langle f, v_n \rangle + (u_m(0),v_n(0))_H$$
by IBP (and recall that $v \in C^1(0,T;V) \subset L^2(0,T;V)$ with $v(T) = 0$.)

My problem is, how to obtain (2) from here? **Specificially, I don't understand why it is true that
$$\int_0^T \langle u_m, v'_n \rangle_{V'V} \to \int_0^T \langle u, v' \rangle_{V'V}.$$**
I am fine with the other terms in the equation. Why is true that $v'_n \to v$ in $L^2(0,T;V)$?

OK, so $v'$ exists and $v_n'$ probably exists assuming we can differentiate the coefficients. But why does it convergence to $v'$? No explanation is given anywhere.

Comment: So something about this doesn't seem right. You're looking for solutions $u \in H^1(\dotsc)$, no? Now you can just test with functions $v_n$, $v \in H^1(\dotsc)$. If $v_n$ converges in $H^1$, then $v_n'$ converges in $L^2(\dotsc)$. If you test with functions $v_n$, $v \in L^2(\dotsc)$, what is $v_n'$ supposed to mean?

Comment: Sort of, so $u \in L^2(0,T;V)$ and $u' \in L^2(0,T;V').$ So suppose we pick our test function $v \in C^1(0,T;V)$. So in particular $v \in L^2(0,T;V)$ and $v' \in L^2(0,T;V)$. All we know (I think) is that there is a sequence $v_n$ converging to $v$ in $L^2(0,T;V)$ and another sequence $w_n$ converging to $v'$ in $L^2(0,T;V)$. I don't even know that $w_n = v_n'$. So basically I don't believe we have that $v_n$ converges in $H^1$. That may be true  for the solution approximation, i.e. $u_m$ may converge in $H^1$ but not for the test space.

Comment: By $u'$ you mean the time-derivative of $u$, right? Then how can you conclude that $u'$ exists and lies in $L^2(0, T; V')$? Same for $v$. If all you know is that $u$ is in $L^2$, then $u$ will not be weakly (time-)differentiable in general.

Comment: Yes, time derivative. Well we know $u'$ exists because we can bound $u_m'$ uniformly and can extract a convergent subsequence. we can show the limit is in fact $u'.$ But our formulation is: find $u \in L^2(0,T;V)$ with $u' \in L^2(0,T;V')$ such that $$\langle u', v \rangle + a(u,v) = \langle f,v \rangle$$ holds for every $v \in L^2(0,T;V).$ Not $v \in H^1$.

Comment: Well, in [Trémolières/Lions/Glowinski: Numerical Analysis of Variational Inequalities; p.408] e.g., such problems are considered. But the function $u$ is required to live in the space $W(0,T) = \{ v \colon v \in L^2(0,T;V), v' \in L^2(0,T; V') \}$ and so are the test functions $v$. The scalar product on that space is given by $(v,w) = (v,w)_{L^2(0,T;V)} + (v',w')_{L^2(0,T;V')}$.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't access that. But hmm, it is interesting if $v$ are also required to be in that space. Because in no other book (Evans, Renardy, ...) does it say that the test functions ought to be in $W(0,T)$..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9209/discussion-between-anonymous-and-matt-w)

Comment: @anonymous Thanks for the comments in the chat, I am unable to reply there for some reason. I think what is done is that, similar to what you say with Renardy, they choose $v = \psi w$, where $\psi$ is a function of time and $w$ is purely spatial. Then perhaps the convergence is simpler as you can factor out the $\psi$.